# Ganache: How to see block data in every node?

Tags: solidity, web3.py, ganache

I'm using ganache to simulate and a local blockchain network, and web3.py to interact with it.

One aspect of blockchain is transparency: all transactions, once mined, are written into the ledgers of every node.

**How do I see this for myself with the ganache GUI?**

I'd like to verify for myself that the tx has been written into all of the nodes

Answer (score 0):

If you are running multiple nodes in the network then you simply need to connect Ganache to the node you want - they are probably running in different ports in localhost.

There is no other separate "blockchain" place, only the nodes. All of the data is in the nodes. So when you connect your Ganache to your node the data you see is the data the node has.

Usually, especially in small networks, all nodes have all the same data. But due to latency some nodes may be lacking behind if the network is a bit bigger. And due to consensus mechanisms different nodes may even have (for a while) conflicting data.